# Not a valid Java Home Error while installing Oracle Web Logic Server

Tags: oracle, cmd, weblogic12c, java-home, jdk1.7

I need help to extract WLS, I tried to install WebLogic Server with CMD and i already setup java_home.
But i've got the following error:

> Extracting the installer . . . . . . Done 
>   This installer must be executed using a Java Development Kit (JDK)
>   but C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 is not a valid JDK Java Home.
>   The log is located here: C:\Users\E440\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2016-12-18_05-38-26AM\launcher2016-12-18_05-38-26AM.log.
>
> Press Enter to exit

I trying to set JAVA_HOME

> C:\Oracle\FMW>set java_home
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

And that is the path that i set in environmet variable, but it still display the same error.
I change the command to specified the oracle home

> C:\Oracle\FMW>java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_quick.jar oracle_home=C:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome

But again the error is still the same.
The *C:\Program Files\Java\jre7*  path is not even in my environment variable.
Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue and found this way around:

1- Copied the installer to the JDK folder you want to use for the installation.
  In my case:    `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin`
 (Just to make it easier to get to it from the command line latter)

2- Open cmd and navigate until the Java JDK folder

3- Then execute the installer using the java in that folder:
 ./java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar

Here is an image of what I did.

(Dont forget to remove the *fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar* from there after the installation is completed)

As I say, is just a way around if you just want to go over the issue and get Weblogic installed. Im sure there are more elegant solutions, but I hope this one helps ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Set up the the path too (in addition to java_home), so the JDK comes before the JRE:

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\<JAVA_VERSION>\bin;%path%
```

Remember to change the `<JAVA_VERSION>` to your JAVA version.

**eg:**

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin;%path%
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran a command `where java` in command prompt and it showed me that the java was installed here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

I deleted this from the **environment variables**  under **path** in windows.